# header inline with selectizeInput

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I would like to add `selectizeInput()` in one line with the header in my shiny app. Moreover I would like to align the header to the left and `selectizeInput()` to the right.

I tried this:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("simplex"),
  titlePanel(title = div(div(style = "display: inline-block; ",
                             "My shiny application"),
                         div(style = "width: 200px; display: inline-block; 
                                      float: right; ",
                             selectInput(inputId = "opt",
                                         label = "",
                                         choices = c("opt1", "opt2", "opt3"),
                                         selected = "opt1")))),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(),
    mainPanel(),
    fluid = F)
))
```

But header and `selectInput()` are not on the same line. When I exclude `float: right` then they are, but they are not properly aligned.

Any suggestions are welcomed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
 shinyUI(fluidPage(
      theme = shinytheme("simplex"),
      tagList(div(div(style = "display: inline-block; ",
                                 h1("My shiny application"),class="main_title"),
                             div(style = "width: 200px; display: inline-block; 
                                          float: right; ",
                                 selectInput(inputId = "opt",
                                             label = "",
                                             choices = c("opt1", "opt2", "opt3"),
                                             selected = "opt1")))),

      sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(),
        mainPanel(),
        fluid = F)
    ))
```